# Can VSCode be configured to add custom "|" (pipe) matching when working with closures in Rust?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, ide, closures

I'm working with *Rust* in *VSCode*.

I would like the `|` to be inserted like a single or double quote.  This is useful when working with closures.

I expect that this can be achieved with a language specification extension, however, I'm using the [rust-lang.rust](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust) extension and want to continue to utilize the 99.9% of the functionality that I get from that.

Comment: Note: you shouldn't use Rust extension, it isn't actively developed. Use rust-analyzer instead.